# What is RENV_PATHS_CACHE_HOST? -- docker documentation

Tags: r, docker, renv

In the docker vignette/documentation, they give an example with a shiny app, but don't exactly specify what their parameters mean. Some of them are self explanatory, but others aren't. More specifically:

https://rstudio.github.io/renv/articles/docker.html

```
RENV_PATHS_CACHE_HOST=/opt/local/renv/cache
RENV_PATHS_CACHE_CONTAINER=/renv/cache
docker run --rm \
    -e "RENV_PATHS_CACHE=${RENV_PATHS_CACHE_CONTAINER}" \
    -v "${RENV_PATHS_CACHE_HOST}:${RENV_PATHS_CACHE_CONTAINER}" \
    -p 14618:14618 \
    R -s -e 'renv::restore(); shiny::runApp(host = "0.0.0.0", port = 14618)'
```

What is **RENV_PATHS_CACHE_HOST**?
And is **RENV_PATHS_CACHE_CONTAINER** the location of where my cache will be upon running the image instance/container?

I'm not entirely sure how to use this example, but feel I'll need it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example here tries to demonstrate how one might mount an `renv` cache from the host filesystem on to a Docker container.

In this case, `RENV_PATHS_CACHE_HOST` points to a (theoretical) cache directory on the host filesystem, at `/opt/local/renv/cache`, whereas `RENV_PATHS_CACHE_CONTAINER` points to the location in the container where the host cache will be visible.

Comment: Do you know why this line is necessary `-p 14618:14618 `. I know we are mapping ports, but why?

Comment: That's just so that you can access the Shiny application running on port 14618 from the host application.